# How to show a password from the AspNetUser table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Is is possible to show the hashed password that resides in the AspNetUser table? because I have grid that shows active admnistrators and when I click on a row I want the fields to be populated for editing and one of those fields is for the password.
Is it possible to "unhash" the password that was created with PasswordHasher or am I left with just having to either generate a new password or to create a new password when the record goes to be edited?

Comment: PasswordHasher is designed to do one way hashing. You probably want to hide this field in your grid, considering its a non-human readable hash. If you need a reset password feature, implement it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That is the idea of hashing. You store the value that represents the actual data. It is only possible to hash or verify hashed value. See: [PasswordHasher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher(v=vs.108).aspx)

If you want to have such a mechanism, you need to use Encryption. Encryption and hashing are different things.

It is only common to store hashed password value since it is not possible to get original value. It is more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to check it out.